# Drag function not working properly HTML,CSS and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a simple Iphone IOS project in which there will be an Iphone frame and user will be able to use it as a phone and some basic features in it like camera, calendar, time etc.... so I was thinking to apply drag up gesture in it just like normal phones have but the drag function in not working I am an beginner so I don't have so much of knowledge in html css and js so please help me solve the issue.

I was making the ios iphone replica project and trying to apply drag up gesture unlock feature in it so I wrote some html css and js for it

```js
const iphone = document.querySelector('.iphone');
const mainScreen = document.querySelector('.main-screen');
const controlBar = document.querySelector('.control');
const lockScreen = document.querySelector('.lockscreen')
let isLocked = true;
let startY = 0;
let currentY = 0;

function unlocked() {
  let isLocked = false;
  mainScreen.style.display = 'flex';
  lockScreen.style.display = 'none';

}

// Hover effect to show control bar
iphone.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
  if (isLocked) {
    controlBar.style.opacity = 1;
    iphone.style.cursor = 'pointer';
  }
});

iphone.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
  if (isLocked) {
    controlBar.style.opacity = 0;
  }
});

// Drag gesture to unlock
iphone.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
  if (isLocked) {
    startY = e.clientY;
    currentY = startY;
    iphone.addEventListener('mousemove', drag);
  }
});

window.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
  if (isLocked) {
    iphone.removeEventListener('mousemove', drag);
    if (currentY - startY < -100) {
      unlockScreen();
    }
  }
});

function drag(e) {
  currentY = e.clientY;
}

function unlockScreen() {
  isLocked = false;
  mainScreen.style.transform = 'translateY(0)';
  controlBar.style.opacity = 1;
  iphone.style.cursor = 'default';
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
}


/* Update the positioning for the info sections */

.info-left,
.info-right {
  font-size: 12px;
  /* Adjust the size as needed */
}


/* Update the positioning for the info sections */

.info-left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  /* Adjust the vertical position as needed */
  left: 10px;
}

.info-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
}

.info-right .signal {
  margin-right: 5px;
  /* Adjust the margin as needed */
}

.info-right .network-type {
  margin-right: 5px;
  /* Adjust the margin as needed */
}

.iphone {
  background-image: url(ios-wallpaper.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 23vw;
  height: 95vh;
  margin: auto;
  color: white;
  border: 10px solid black;
  border-radius: 30px;
  position: relative;
}

.notch {
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  height: 4vh;
  width: 9vw;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  left: 80px;
}

.speaker {
  background-color: rgba(48, 47, 47, 0.6);
  box-shadow: 2px solid rgb(88, 88, 88);
  height: 3px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.front-cam {
  margin-left: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  top: 6px;
  height: 14px;
  width: 14px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px rgba(26, 25, 25, 0.2);
}

.lens {
  height: 6px;
  width: 6px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(216, 216, 216, 0.7);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.lens img {
  height: 12px;
  width: 13px;
}

.DateAndTime {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 15vh;
}

.bottom {
  position: relative;
  bottom: -350px;
}

.flashlight {
  position: relative;
  background-color: black;
  height: 6vh;
  width: 3vw;
  left: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 500px;
}

.camera {
  position: relative;
  background-color: black;
  height: 6vh;
  width: 3vw;
  right: -210px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 500px;
  bottom: 6vh;
}

.control {
  width: 10vw;
  height: 3px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  left: 30%;
  bottom: -40px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.main-screen {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  /* Customize the background color */
  display: none;
  /* Hide by default */
  transition: transform 0.3s ease;
  z-index: -1;
  /* Place it behind the lock screen */
}

.iphone.hovered.control {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta3/css/all.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@6.2.1/css/fontawesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-QYIZto+st3yW+o8+5OHfT6S482Zsvz2WfOzpFSXMF9zqeLcFV0/wlZpMtyFcZALm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>IOS : Replica</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="iphone">
      <div class="notch">
        <div class="speaker"></div>
        <div class="front-cam">
          <div class="lens"><img src="lens.png" alt=""></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="lockscreen">

        <div class="DateAndTime">
          <h1 class="lock-time">11:57</h1>
          <p class="date">Saturday, 26 August</p>
        </div>
        <div class="info-left">
          <div class="operator">
            Airtel
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="info-right">
          <div class="signal">
            <i class="fas fa-signal"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="network-type">
            5G
          </div>
          <ion-icon name="battery-half-outline"></ion-icon>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">

          <div class="control"></div>

          <div class="flashlight">
            <ion-icon name="flashlight"></ion-icon>
          </div>

          <div class="camera">
            <i class="fas fa-camera"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="main-screen"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@7.1.0/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
<script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@7.1.0/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>

<script src="script.js"></script>

</html>
```

Please check the code and someone help me in this problem I want that the main screen (which is currently empty) should appear when someone drags up on the screen or the control bar and the lock screen should disappear but it is not happening

Comment: Others are not going to check your code, please re-write this with the actual problem up top as well. What do you mean by not happening? What is happening instead? The main screen and text is all white, so we are not able to view it, please re style.

Answer (score 0):

Within the `mouseup` callback if you add the `currentY=e.clientY`, making sure that the event handler assigns `e` as the event, then I think your code does what you want. I added some CSS to help illustrate what happens when you drag up by more than designated amount (screen will turn green)

```js
const iphone = document.querySelector('.iphone');
const mainScreen = document.querySelector('.main-screen');
const controlBar = document.querySelector('.control');
const lockScreen = document.querySelector('.lockscreen')
let isLocked = true;
let startY = 0;
let currentY = 0;

function unlocked() {
  let isLocked = false;
  mainScreen.style.display = 'flex';
  lockScreen.style.display = 'none';

}

// Hover effect to show control bar
iphone.addEventListener('mouseenter', (e) => {
  if (isLocked) {
    currentY=e.clientY;
    controlBar.style.opacity = 1;
    iphone.style.cursor = 'pointer';
  }
});

iphone.addEventListener('mouseleave', (e) => {
  if (isLocked) {
    controlBar.style.opacity = 0;
  }
});

// Drag gesture to unlock
iphone.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
  if (isLocked) {
    startY = e.clientY;
    currentY = startY;
  }
});

window.addEventListener('mouseup', (e) => {
  if (isLocked) {
    currentY=e.clientY;
    if (currentY - startY < -100) {
      unlockScreen();
    }
  }
});

function drag(e) {
  currentY = e.clientY;
}

function unlockScreen() {
  isLocked = false;
  mainScreen.style.transform = 'translateY(0)';
  controlBar.style.opacity = 1;
  iphone.style.cursor = 'default';
  iphone.style.background='rgba(0,255,0,0.25)';
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
}


/* Update the positioning for the info sections */

.info-left,
.info-right {
  font-size: 12px;
  /* Adjust the size as needed */
}


/* Update the positioning for the info sections */

.info-left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  /* Adjust the vertical position as needed */
  left: 10px;
}

.info-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
}

.info-right .signal {
  margin-right: 5px;
  /* Adjust the margin as needed */
}

.info-right .network-type {
  margin-right: 5px;
  /* Adjust the margin as needed */
}

.iphone {
  background-image: url(ios-wallpaper.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 23vw;
  height: 95vh;
  margin: auto;
  color: white;
  border: 10px solid black;
  border-radius: 30px;
  position: relative;
}

.notch {
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  height: 4vh;
  width: 9vw;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  left: 80px;
}

.speaker {
  background-color: rgba(48, 47, 47, 0.6);
  box-shadow: 2px solid rgb(88, 88, 88);
  height: 3px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.front-cam {
  margin-left: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  top: 6px;
  height: 14px;
  width: 14px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px rgba(26, 25, 25, 0.2);
}

.lens {
  height: 6px;
  width: 6px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(216, 216, 216, 0.7);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.lens img {
  height: 12px;
  width: 13px;
}

.DateAndTime {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 15vh;
}

.bottom {
  position: relative;
  bottom: -350px;
}

.flashlight {
  position: relative;
  background-color: black;
  height: 6vh;
  width: 3vw;
  left: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 500px;
}

.camera {
  position: relative;
  background-color: black;
  height: 6vh;
  width: 3vw;
  right: -210px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 500px;
  bottom: 6vh;
}

.control {
  width: 10vw;
  height: 3px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  left: 30%;
  bottom: -40px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.main-screen {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  /* Customize the background color */
  display: none;
  /* Hide by default */
  transition: transform 0.3s ease;
  z-index: -1;
  /* Place it behind the lock screen */
}

.iphone.hovered.control {
  opacity: 1;
}


.DateAndTime,.operator{
  color:black
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta3/css/all.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@6.2.1/css/fontawesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-QYIZto+st3yW+o8+5OHfT6S482Zsvz2WfOzpFSXMF9zqeLcFV0/wlZpMtyFcZALm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>IOS : Replica</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="iphone">
      <div class="notch">
        <div class="speaker"></div>
        <div class="front-cam">
          <div class="lens"><img src="lens.png" alt=""></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="lockscreen">

        <div class="DateAndTime">
          <h1 class="lock-time">11:57</h1>
          <p class="date">Saturday, 26 August</p>
        </div>
        <div class="info-left">
          <div class="operator">
            Airtel
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="info-right">
          <div class="signal">
            <i class="fas fa-signal"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="network-type">
            5G
          </div>
          <ion-icon name="battery-half-outline"></ion-icon>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">

          <div class="control"></div>

          <div class="flashlight">
            <ion-icon name="flashlight"></ion-icon>
          </div>

          <div class="camera">
            <i class="fas fa-camera"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="main-screen"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@7.1.0/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
<script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@7.1.0/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>

<script src="script.js"></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Read this article on [pointer events](https://javascript.info/pointer-events).

**Details are commented in example**

***View in [Full page](https://i.ibb.co/PGyZT2x/fullpage.png) mode -- Initial display within `<iframe>` is not rendered correctly***

```js
// Reference .iphone, .lock, and .main
const iphone = document.querySelector(".iphone");
const lock = document.querySelector(".lock");
const main = document.querySelector(".main");

/**
 * Register the "pointerdown" event to .lock
 * Call event handler unlock(e) when event is triggered
 */
lock.onpointerdown = unlock;

// Event handler passes (e)vent Object by default
function unlock(e) {
  // Get current height of .iphone in px
  const total = iphone.clientHeight;
  // Define start vertical position coordinate
  const start = e.clientY;
  // Define element registered to event
  const lock = e.currentTarget;
  // Retarget all pointer events to .lock
  lock.setPointerCapture(e.pointerId);

  // Register "pointermove" event to .lock
  lock.onpointermove = e => {
    // If user drags up more than 25% of .iphone height...
    let dist = start - e.clientY;
    let perc = (dist / total) * 100;
    if (perc > 25) {
      // ...open .main...
      main.classList.add("open");
      // ...close .lock
      lock.classList.add("close");
    }
  };

  // Register "pointerup" event to .lock
  lock.onpointerup = e => {
    // Remove pointer events
    lock.onpointermove = null;
    lock.onpointerup = null;
  };
};
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu&display=swap');

/**
 * When font-size is defined on <html> element, 1rem will equal
 * the font-size. ex. 1rem = 5vmin
 * 5vmin = 5vh if viewport height is less than viewport width
 * OR 
 * 5vmin = 5vw if viewport width is less than viewport height
 */

:root {
  font: 5vmin/1 'Ubuntu';
}

.center {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.stack {
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
}


/**
 * This is the "frame"
 */

.iphone {
  position: relative;
  width: 27vw;
  height: 95vh;
  margin: auto;
  border: 0.5rem solid black;
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: white;
  background: rgb(43, 87, 124);
  overflow: hidden;
}


/**
 * Both "screens" hide any content that goes beyond it's borders
 */

section {
  overflow: hidden;
}

time {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}


/**
 * This is the lockscreen.
 * It is positioned within the borders of .iphone
 */

.lock {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 95vh;
  background: url(https://w0.peakpx.com/wallpaper/413/669/HD-wallpaper-blue-aesthetic-atmosphere-cloud-new-peace-lockscreen-iphone-android.jpg) no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  /* Initial position for animation */
  transform: translateY(0%);
  /* If transform value changes, this animation activates */
  transition: transform 0.8s ease-in;
}

.lock header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.lock .time {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}


/**
 * This is the mainscreen.
 * It sits above .iphone, hidden.
 */

.main {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 95vh;
  background: url(https://mcdn.wallpapersafari.com/medium/52/55/Es4tdg.jpg) no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  /* Initial position for animation */
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  /* If transform value changes, this animation activates */
  transition: transform 0.8s ease-in;
}

.main header {
  position: relative;
  height: 3vh;
  padding: 0.25rem;
  font-size: 0.5rem;
}

.main .time {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 8vw;
  text-align: center;
}

.main .notch {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 9vw;
  background-color: black;
  height: 3vh;
  width: 9vw;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}

.main .status {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 18vw;
  width: 8vw;
  text-align: center;
}

.main .status * {
  margin-left: 0.2rem;
}

.main .apps {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
  width: 24vw;
  min-height: 75vh;
  margin: 2vh auto;
}

.main .icon {
  display: block;
  min-width: 4.5vw;
  min-height: 4.5vw;
  margin: 0.5rem 0.2rem;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.main footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20vh;
}

.main nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3vw;
}

.main menu {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
}

.main li {
  width: 0.25rem;
  height: 0.25rem;
  margin: 0 0.25rem;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.main .active {
  background: white
}

.main .control {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2vh;
  width: 24vw;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding: 0.25rem;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.main .control .icon {
  min-width: 5vw;
  min-height: 5vw;
  margin: 0.25rem;
}

.time::before {
  content: attr(data-time);
}

.date::before {
  content: attr(data-date);
}

.open {
  transform: translateY(0%);
}

.close {
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Iphone Mockup</title>
  <!-- 
    Only one <link> is needed to use Font-Awesome 
  -->
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- 
    The custom CSS can be placed within <style> OR in a external stylesheet using 
    <link href="file.css"> 
  -->
  <style></style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="iphone">
    <!-- 
      Lockscreen 
    -->
    <section class="lock">
      <header class="center stack">
        <time class="time" data-time="1:45 AM"></time>
        <time class="date" data-date="August 26, 2023"></time>
      </header>
    </section>
    <!-- 
      Mainscreen 
    -->
    <section class="main">
      <header>
        <time class="time" data-time="1:45 AM"></time>
        <div class="notch"></div>
        <div class="status">
          <i class="fas fa-signal"></i>
          <b>5G</b>
          <i class="fas fa-battery"></i>
        </div>
      </header>
      <main class="apps">
        <ion-icon name="aperture" class="icon center"></ion-icon>
        <ion-icon name="basketball" class="icon center"></ion-icon>
        <ion-icon name="baseball" class="icon center"></ion-icon>
        <ion-icon name="rocket" class="icon center"></ion-icon>
        <ion-icon name="trophy" class="icon center"></ion-icon>
        <ion-icon name="logo-pinterest" class="icon center"></ion-icon>
        <ion-icon name="logo-chrome" class="icon center"></ion-icon>
      </main>
      <footer class="center stack">
        <nav class="center">
          <menu class="center">
            <li class="active">&nbsp;</li>
            <li>&nbsp;</li>
            <li>&nbsp;</li>
          </menu>
        </nav>
        <menu class="center control">
          <ion-icon name="call" class="icon center"></ion-icon>
          <ion-icon name="flashlight" class="icon center"></ion-icon>
          <ion-icon name="camera" class="icon center"></ion-icon>
          <ion-icon name="compass" class="icon center"></ion-icon>
        </menu>
      </footer>
    </section>
  </div>
  <!-- 
    <script> should be before end tag of </body>, not after it 
  -->
  <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@7.1.0/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
  <!-- 
    Custom JavaScript can be placed within <script> OR in an external .JS file using 
    <script src="file.js"> 
  -->
  <script></script>
</body>

</html>
```